# How to test component that depend on config set on app.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-testing-library

I'm trying to run a test that checks if the `history.goBack` has been called, by using `jest.fn`. I have set my routes in app.js with an outer `FirebaseConfigProvider`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <FirebaseConfigProvider>
        <AutomaticRedirectContextProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path={PAGES.HOME} component={HomePage} />

            <Route path={PAGES.CONFIRMATION} component={ConfirmationPage} />
          </Routes>
        </AutomaticRedirectContextProvider>
      </FirebaseConfigProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And I'm using the `createMemoryHistory()` to set initialEntries with pathname and state, however the test seems to ignore the configuration from `FirebaseConfigProvider`, set in app.js.

confirm.js

```
export default function ConfirmationPage() {
  const handleGoBack = () => {
    // this line works when running the app, but breaks when running the test
    firebase.analytics().logEvent('click_back_button', firebaseAnalyticsData); 

    history.goBack();
  };
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
}
```

confirm.test.js

```
import { mockPerson } from '../mocks/person';
const mockHistoryGoBack = jest.fn();

async function setupPage() {
  await wait(async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory({initialEntries: [
      {
        pathname: PAGES.CONFIRMATION.replace(
          ':id',
          1
        ),
        state: mockPerson
      }
    ]});
    history.goBack = mockHistoryGoBack;
    render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <ConfirmationPage />
      </Router>
    );
  });
}

describe('View/Pages/Confirmation', () => {
  it('calls history.goBack when back button is clicked', async () => {
    await setupPage();

    const backButton = screen.getByTestId(HISTORY_BACK_ID);
    fireEvent.click(backButton);
    expect(mockHistoryGoBack).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
}
```

I have also tried with  but got the same results. Error `"TypeError: _firebase.default.analytics is not a function"` on this line from confirm.js: `firebase.analytics().logEvent('click_back_button', firebaseAnalyticsData);`

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check with FirebaseConfigProvider on how to test with it?

Comment: I have two other views being tested and they run without any problem. The difference between these tests is that this one uses `Router` instead of `MemoryRouter` and it is testing the `history.goBack()` by mocking it. The tests from the other views are checking just for content.